# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Web interface router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I found and old router that I want to use, but I cant get it to work, is a TPLINK TD-W8980.

The router broadcast both SSID but when I want to access the local IP it loads badly, image:

[image: Web interface].

There is wrong styles over the web, and you can click log in button but is not visible. After some seconds or if I click log in, I can't access any more because of `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I tried, a firmware recovery but can't connect it through `tftp`, factory reset and ethernet connection

Comment: Probably needs a firmware refresh, but doing so when it's in this shape will be very technical.

Comment: Also some old routers need IE11 to open them.  Make sure you are using Chromium Edge to see if that works (may not).

Comment: same error, yes i tried ftpf with 192.168.0.66 but no information receive on log

Comment: The router is old (you say) and so it may be past recovering at this point.

Comment: like 6 years, maybe i should change it, I thought it would be possible to recover it

Comment: For a consumer router of that age, yes, I think time to replace with a more modern router, more modern firmware, and Chromium support router management.